# Handling keyup event with message passing in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, message-passing

I am new to chrome extension development. I am trying to create an extension consist of a text field and a button. If user enters some text in text-field, then exact thing should automatically get entered login-id field of HTML page.

Here are my files..

Popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
"browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key  
with
value "popup.html".
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Email Extension</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <center>
       Enter email id:
       <br>
       <br>
       <input type="text" id="txtEmail">
       <br>
       <br>
       <input type="button" id="btnClear" value=" Clear ">
    </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Popup.js

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var btnElement = document.getElementById("btnClear");
    var txtElement = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
    // onClick's logic below:
    btnElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
        clearField();
    });

    txtElement.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        changeEmail();
    });

    function clearField() {
        txtElement.value = "";
    }

    function changeEmail() {
        var emailId = txtElement.value;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:emailId}, function(response) {
            console.log("written");
        });
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Email Extension",
  "description": "This extension allows the user to enter Email id for login.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click to Enter user id"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

myscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        var email = document.getElementById("login_username");
        email.value = request.msg;
        console.log(request);
        console.log(sender);
        console.log(email.value);
    }
);
```

Its just showing "written" on console. Not displaying request, sender content at console, also not entering anything in `login_username`

Can anybody please help to figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: You don't appear to have an element with the ID `login_username`. Also, you can't use an addon to change the information a user has to enter to log in to a system with. You'd need to update the actual login process on the server to handle that.

Comment: @Obsidian, lets consider `login_username` is available at some webpage as this extension works for any page. And the page on which I am working there it is present.

Comment: Just an interim thought. You know that the console you need to view for the popup messages is not where the messages from myscript.js will appear, you need to be inspecting the web page to see those - just in case.

Comment: You cannot send a message to a content script using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. You have to use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` with the id of the tab where your content script is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send a message to a content script using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. You have to use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` with the id of the tab where your content script is running. For example, to send it to currently active tab, you could use something like:

```
function changeEmail(){
    var emailId = txtElement.value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tabs){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{msg:emailId}, function(response) {
            console.log("written");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: **"with the id of the tab where your content script is running"**

My question here is, content script should run at current page by default no?

Comment: According to your manifest, your content script runs on every page, but still you need the tab id to send the message.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, YOU SAVED MY LIFE, ITS WORKS

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Apologize for grammatical mistake done by excitement :)

*IT WORKS